# After focusing for a long time, why do certain activities have the effect of refreshing or rejuvenating your mind?

Tags: learning, motivation, attention

If you've been studying or otherwise engaging in mental work, there are certain activities which are often recommended to "refresh your mind" when you are tired. Here are some common examples:

- Taking a walk outside, generally enjoying nature
- Listening to music
- Doing something creative like drawing, dancing, or singing
- Unplugging from social media
- Meditating

What does "refreshing" technically mean in this context?
Why do we sometimes feel like our brains need to be refreshed in the first place?
What do the above activities have in common which makes them especially conducive to this refreshing?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-is-it-that-taking-a-break-from-a-problem-sometimes-allows-you-to-figure-out